# Deleting In Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am learning Room DataBase!!
I Know How to Insert and Retrieve Data from Room DataBase to Recycler View!! But In Delete Operation I am getting error of "No Adapter attached Skipped Layout!"

What I want when anyone click on delete button on recycler view . The Task should be deleted

That's why I also Used delete method in Interface and add Interface in Recycler View Adapter which give call back to MainActivity so that we delete and update the recycler view

All of my codes are given below

Here is my Entity Class named as Task

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate =  true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_name")
    private String task_name;
    @ColumnInfo
    private String task_desc;
    @ColumnInfo
    private String comment;

    @ColumnInfo
    private String task_comp_date;
    @ColumnInfo
    private String activate;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTask_name() {
        return task_name;
    }

    public void setTask_name(String task_name) {
        this.task_name = task_name;
    }

    public String getTask_desc() {
        return task_desc;
    }

    public void setTask_desc(String task_desc) {
        this.task_desc = task_desc;
    }

    public String getTask_comp_date() {
        return task_comp_date;
    }

    public void setTask_comp_date(String task_comp_date) {
        this.task_comp_date = task_comp_date;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getActivate() {
        return activate;
    }

    public void setActivate(String activate) {
        this.activate = activate;
    }


}
```

My Data Accession Object named as TaskDao

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task")
    List<Task> getAll();
    @Insert
    void insert(Task task);
    @Delete
    void delete(Task task);
    @Update
    void update(Task task);
}
```

My DataBase

```
@Database(entities = {Task.class},version = 1)
public abstract class AppDataBase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract TaskDao taskDao();


}
```

My DataBaseClient named as DatabaseClient

```
public class DatabaseClient {
    private Context context;
    private static DatabaseClient mInstace;

    private AppDataBase appDataBase;

    public DatabaseClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        appDataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(context,AppDataBase.class,"MyDailyTask").build();
    }
    public static synchronized DatabaseClient getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(mInstace == null)
        {
            mInstace = new DatabaseClient(context);
        }
        return mInstace;
    }
    public AppDataBase getAppDataBase()
    {
        return appDataBase;
    }
}
```

My RecyclerView Adapter

```
        public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Task> taskList;
public interface OnDeleteClickListener
    {
        void OnDeleteClickListener(Task task);
    }
    private OnDeleteClickListener onDeleteClickListener;

    public TaskAdapter(Context context, List<Task> taskList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.taskList = taskList;
    }

    public void setOnDeleteClickListener(OnDeleteClickListener onDeleteClickListener) {
        this.onDeleteClickListener = onDeleteClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
       view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_task_list,parent,false);
       MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
       return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.setData(taskList.get(position).getTask_name(),taskList.get(position).getTask_desc(),taskList.get(position).getComment(),taskList.get(position).getTask_comp_date(),position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return taskList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
        private ImageView view;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            t1= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCommnt);
            t2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
            t3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            t4= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStart);
            t5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEnd);
            view =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdele);


        }
        public void  setData(String t01, String t02, String t03, String t05, final int position)
        {
            t1.setText("Task Comment               "+t03);
            t2.setText("Task Description           "+t02);
            t3.setText("Task Name                    "+ t01);
            t4.setText("Start  ");
            t5.setText("Ënd    "+t05);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(onDeleteClickListener!=null)
                    {
                        onDeleteClickListener.OnDeleteClickListener(taskList.get(position));
                        taskList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private RecyclerView recyclerView;
       ImageView imageView;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           imageView = findViewById(R.id.ivAdd);
           recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvTask);
           imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTaskActivity.class));
               }
           });
           new newTask().execute();
       }

class newTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, List<Task>> implements TaskAdapter.OnDeleteClickListener {
    List<Task> tasks;
    @Override
    protected List<Task> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

         tasks = DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDataBase().taskDao().getAll();

        return  tasks;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Task> tasks) {
        super.onPostExecute(tasks);
        TaskAdapter taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(MainActivity.this,tasks);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
        taskAdapter.setOnDeleteClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void OnDeleteClickListener(final Task task) {
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDataBase().taskDao().delete(task);

    }
},1000);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome in stack

you interface is declared but not assign so your will throw null pointer when click on item inside your list, but good work your check null before fire method interface

first add setter for `OnDeleteClickListener` inside your **adapter**

```
public void setOnDeleteClickListener(OnDeleteClickListener listener){
 this.onDeleteClickListener=listener;
}
```

and also add code that remove item from you list when user click item
so inside `setData` method update this code

```
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (onDeleteClickListener != null) {
            onDeleteClickListener.OnDeleteClickListener(taskList.get(position));
            //remove item from list and then notify adapter data is changed
            taskList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

finally to Triggers `onDeleteClickListener` inside your `AsyncTask` 
update your code here

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(List < Task > tasks) {
     super.onPostExecute(tasks);
     TaskAdapter taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(MainActivity.this, tasks, this);
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
     recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
     recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

     //pass this that refer to my interface 
     taskAdapter.setOnDeleteClickListener(this);


 }
```

inside your OnDelete just use this code to run in another thread

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDataBase().taskDao().delete(task);

    }
});
```

> **Advice** : Don't name your variable or arguments like String 
>   t01,String  t02..etc ,choice name for like what this variable  jop
>   like String taskComment,String taskName ..etc

i hope this help you

Comment: Thank You So Much

Comment: @PiyushJaiswal your welcome, please make my answer correct and vote up if that help you

Comment: I also set value using constructor

Comment: But how it is deleting from Room Database

Comment: pass tasks from OnDeleteClickListener  to DeleteTask

Comment: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:351)
        at com.piyushjaiswal121.diary.TaskDao_Impl.delete(TaskDao_Impl.java:130)
        at com.piyushjaiswal121.diary.MainActivity$newTask.OnDeleteClickListener(MainActivity.java:61)
        at com.piyushjaiswal121.diary.TaskAdapter$MyViewHolder$1.onClick(TaskAdapter.java:79)

Comment: InSide AsyncTask                                                                             @Override
        public void OnDeleteClickListener(final Task task) {

            DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDataBase().taskDao().delete(task);


        }

Comment: When I used Handler it works for one task. after one task is deleted and i go to delete second task it show  Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: Can I have to create new Async task for delete operation in  @Override
        public void OnDeleteClickListener(final Task task) {  If yes How!!!

Comment: try to use AsyncTask.execute(); replaced with handler

Comment: Okay!!            I try to go for Async Task

Comment: I am Unable to add Asynctask inside onDelete!! Please Help

Comment: use static method not add new class , i will update my answer to show

Comment: @PiyushJaiswal your welcome,Good Work please make my answer correct and vote up if that help you